# sqlserver laravel auto truncate fields

Tags: sql-server, laravel

I just hunted down a nasty bug. I couldn't save to a table because the input data was longer than the field.

Is there a way to tell sqlserver or laravel to ignore this and auto truncate all values that are too long?

Or do I have to do this with substr everytime I assign a value to a model field?

Comment: Can you share an example and explain along with it

Answer (score 0):

You should always validate the data you are inserting in the database.

That being said, you can set `ANSI_WARNINGS` to `off` to prevent SQL Server warning you that String/Binary data will be truncated.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-warnings-transact-sql